# Showing a sum is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For every $r>0$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, I want to show that
$$\sum_{k\in\frac{1}{4} \cdot \mathbb{Z} +t \\ |k|<(r-1)} \frac{1}{1+|r-|k||}\bigg(\frac{1}{(1+||k|-r|)^N} + \big(\frac{l}{\sqrt{r^2-k^2}}\big)^M\bigg)^2 < C$$
where $N,M$ are arbitrary non-negative integers and $C$ is uniform in $r$ and $l$. Moreover, $l\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$  satisfies $\frac{l}{\sqrt{r^2-k^2}}<1.$

I used formula $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ and solved easily for first and second terms. But the third term is bothering me.

Comment: It seems that the expression is a finite sum of finite terms. How can it be not finite? Besides, it is not clear what you mean with the word "double".

Comment: @user It seems not "double sum". I'll edit. By the way, why is it finite in uniform in $r$? since $r$ can be every positive real number, I think the $C$ would be depending on $r$.

Comment: As you have $|k|<r-1$, the number of terms is finite for any finite $r $.

Comment: @user Generally, is "$C$ is uniform in $r$" meaning that '$C$ is constant for $r$' or 'for any $r$, we can choose (or find) finite $C(r)$'? If former is right, we can't use the word "uniform" since $C$ would be different for each $r$. If latter is, I understood it.

Comment: I mean the title of your question. It seems to be not appropriate.